# How do I save map settings as the default when starting a new game?

Tags: civilization-5

Is it possible to save the Civ V game settings so when I start a new map they would be (for example):

- Napolean
- Large Map
- Epic
- No Barbarians
- Prince
- etc...,

So that every time I play I don't have to manually configure them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of those settings can be changed by editing the settings in `%userprofile%\My Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization 5\config.ini` in the `[Game]` section.

- `WorldSize`
- `SeaLevel`
- `QuickHandicap`
- `GameSpeed`
- etc.

Comment: Is it possible to change the advanced settings? Like No Ruins etc?

Comment: @Layke: I didn't see any settings in that file that looked like they were for setting "No Ruins" or several of the other settings you mentioned. There may be a way though — I haven't looked into editing any of the XML files yet though. Maybe there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw a way to default quick combat on, but I can't recall it offhand.

Answer (score 2):

**In the base game**

In addition to editing the obviously-named settings in `%userprofile%\My Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization 5\config.ini`, you can also edit the advanced settings via the GameOptions entry in that same file.  This defaults to `EMPTY` but can be changed to a string of binary digits that represent the advanced settings checkboxes.

I believe the order is dependent on the order of the settings in `steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\Gameplay\XML\GameInfo\CIV5GameOptions.xml`.  There's [a forum thread](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=409261) that gives some of the order/values to try as well.

**As of the Gods and Kings expansion, things have changed a bit.**

The "normal" game settings seem to persist, and I believe these are kept the config.ini file.

The advanced settings *also* persist, and these are stored in a sqlite database - `%userprofile%\My Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization 5\cache\Civ5UserHistoryDatabase.db` in the table AdvancedSettings_GameOptions.  The table schema is "Name" and "Value."

Names are from the `type` field in two files, `CIV5GameOptions.xml` as above, and `steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\DLC\Expansion\Gameplay\XML\GameInfo\CIV5GameOptions_Expansion.xml` for the new expansion options.

You can edit the `Civ5UserHistoryDatabase.db` file with a sqlite editor (such as [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)), although starting a new game with different options will cause this file to be updated automatically.  Deleting the `Civ5UserHistoryDatabase.db` file will cause your settings to reset, and it will be regenerated to the 'empty state' the next time you load the game.  The value of GameOptions in `config.ini` appears to be ignored in the expansion case.

This sqlite database also contains other tables that seem to duplicate the `config.ini` settings, and I believe that the game considers the `Civ5UserHistoryDatabase.db` settings prior to considering the `config.ini` settings, although I haven't tested this extensively.

There's a couple of corner cases, though - specifically quick combat and quick movement.  These two were moved into the Options menu on the "Game Options" tab.  The values set on the "advanced setup" screen don't seem to persist, but you can check the boxes on the options screen to override the "default off" behavior.

There are several "hidden" options that can be set via the database method that aren't in the advanced option menu.  I have not played with these extensively, and I don't know if they're intended for debug (and are therefore unsupported) or for modders (and are therefore fully implemented), so toggle them at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

When I start a map, I do this via the Mods menu and not the single game menu. This is because I hope for a larger variety of random maps.

The problem with the mod menu is that is does not save your selection changes. The single game one does.

So what i do when I want to change the defaults is change them in the single game path and actually start a game. Once you see your settler, exit the game and enter the Mods menu and you will see your defaults ready for you.

I have not seen a way to make the advanced option save. Two options I like to turn on are Raging Barbs and Quick Combat.

Since I play with all random settings and with the play-it-as-it-lays to hope for some hard fought defeats, I dont have to change my default settings anymore. But this woas how I did it before i started this way of playing.